# How to ignore system font scale?

Tags: android, textview, android-theme, android-fonts

When I use it as below, 16f may look too big or too small depending on the font size coming from the system. But I already use a feature in the application where it can select the font scale type. I want to use my own size by ignoring the font scale size from the phone's system. How do I do this?

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text size in pixels, which will be independent of the system font scale.

```
// set the text size in pixels
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 24f)
```